# "Oxford Guide to English Grammar" says "lime" is a pronoun. But I think it's a noun

Tags: pronouns

Oxford Guide to English Grammar; John Eastwood; Oxford University Press 1994-09

[image]

Comment: This is clearly a typo; the original might have been some combination of *him, I, me*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That image you posted is, I am pretty sure, of a version of the material in the book created by OCR (Optical Character Recognition), and possibly processed by some spellchecking software. This could have been done during conversion to Adobe PDF format. You do not state the source of your image. It could be an unofficial scanned copy. Searchable plain-text versions are present on the web and they contain the "lime" alleged pronoun example. I am pretty sure that "lime" is an OCR error for `I/me`, which would make sense in that place. `I/me` is frequently found in discussions of pronouns in linguistic texts , such as the one I show part of  here, "The Distribution of Pronoun Case Forms in English", a doctoral thesis by Heidi Quinn (University of Canterbury, 2002):

https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/35464463.pdf

Below is a screen grab (an actual image) of part of the text as it appears in a PDF reader. If you open the PDF and copy-and-paste some of the text with embedded slashes, sometimes they paste as lower-case Ls. This is probably the origin of the error you have noticed.

> [image]

[image]

It seems as if the PDF contains within itself a plain-text "copy", intended to be, but not always, identical with what you see on screen, and when you paste from it, that's what you get.

I have also noticed that Google searches (e.g. for "lime pronoun"), show "lime" in the results list extract where the page listed actually shows "I/me".